# ClassNotFoundException: MyBatis3Simple

Tags: mybatis-generator

When I use mybatis-generator to autogeneration mappers xml and model from mysql,but I got the Error:

```
[INFO] --- mybatis-generator-maven-plugin:1.3.0:generate (default-cli) @ loanmanager ---
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot instantiate object of type MyBatis3Simple
    at org.mybatis.generator.internal.ObjectFactory.createInternalObject(ObjectFactory.java:136) ...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MyBatis3Simple
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
```

The generator config is:

```
**<generatorConfiguration>
    <!--<properties resource="">-->
    <!--</properties>-->

    <!-- 配置成你本地的mysql-connector-java jar -->
    <classPathEntry
            location="/Users/shenbin/.m2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.40/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar" />
<context id="baseTradeTables" targetRuntime="MyBatis3Simple" defaultModelType="flat">
<property name="beginningDelimiter" value="`"/>
        <property name="endingDelimiter" value="`"/>

        ...
</context>
</generatorConfiguration>**
```

The pom.xml is :

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mybatis.generator</groupId>
                <artifactId>mybatis-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

But It runned OK if I use MyBatis3.

Answer (score 0):

You are using 1.3.0, but MyBatis3Simple added since version 1.3.2 .
[see this for detail](http://www.mybatis.org/generator/whatsNew.html)